# Google importxml - return results per specific criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following code in two cells side by side which works to return a list of stores selling gift cards along with their respective discounts.

=importxml("http://www.giftcardgranny.com/store/7-for-all-mankind","//td[@class='seller']")

=importxml("http://www.giftcardgranny.com/store/7-for-all-mankind/","//td[@class='save']")
I then have the following code which returns the max discount across all 'ebay' stores.

=QUERY(A:B, "select max(B) where A='eBay - Buy It Now'")

Im trying to get the final value (the max ebay discount) to be output by only one single query. I've tried the following query(importxml) to no avail and a number of other methods.

=query(importxml(K10, "//td[@class='seller']|//td[@class='save']"), "SELECT * WHERE Col1 contains 'eBay - Buy It Now'")

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it using this formula:

=index(split(query(arrayformula(query(importxml("http://www.giftcardgranny.com/store/7-for-all-mankind","//td[@class='seller']"), "SELECT * Limit 10",0)&"|"&query(importxml("http://www.giftcardgranny.com/store/7-for-all-mankind/","//td[@class='save']"), "SELECT * Limit 10",0)), "SELECT * WHERE Col1 CONTAINS 'eBay - Buy' ORDER BY Col1 ASC LIMIT 1", 0), "|", 0), 1, 2)

The biggest problem for your initial input was that one of the defined ranges where bigger than the other (10 vs 11 rows). Spreadsheet tends to not see import-functions as ranges unless you query on top of them thus the join, split and order by through an arrayformula.